# How to detect p-autocomplete ( PrimeNG ) text input change (not value)

Tags: angular, primeng

```
<p-autoComplete
              id="members"
              formControlName="companyId"
              field="name"
              placeholder="{{ 'SearchByName' | translate }}"
              styleClass="width100p"
              [suggestions]="companyList"
              (keyup)="onKeyup()"
              (onSelect)="onSelect()"
              (onUnselect)="onUnSelect()"
              (completeMethod)="searchCompany($event)"
              (onKeyUp)="checkValidity($event)"
              (onFocus)="checkValidity($event)"
              (onBlur)="checkValidity($event)"
              (onShow)="helperService.addScroll('.ui-autocomplete-panel')"
              [multiple]="true">
              <ng-template let-company pTemplate="item">
                <div>{{ company.name }}</div>
              </ng-template>
</p-autoComplete>
```

How to detect p-autocomplete ( PrimeNG ) text input change (not value). I want to detect every change in input field. How to detect it? I can detect it with `(completeMethod)` but it is working not correct in case <if 1 char is inputed and you delete it> , (onKeyUp) but it shows only last key up; How to take input string value?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind ngModel and ngModelChange but you'll have to apply ngModelOptions = {"standalone": true} in order to get around a binding errorsince you also appear to be using Reactive Forms.

Alternatively bind to (change) but you'll only get an event per keypress.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$event.target.value` to get the value of your textbox.

```
(keyup)="checkValidity($event.target.value)"
```